# Target release_unpack_ios failed

Tags: flutter

I have been facing the error for the past days while trying to achieve my code for distribution to app store in `Xcode`, I have seen related issues but nothing resolved mine. below is the error message:

> error: Target release_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Binary
> /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cdqizrreamhujihlgmsglqrmqnez/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Flutter.framework/Flutter
> does not contain . Running lipo -info: Non-fat file:
> /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cdqizrreamhujihlgmsglqrmqnez/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Flutter.framework/Flutter
> is architecture: arm64

All certificate and identifier were installed